# while using Pretrained LLM - RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, large-language-model

I am new to LLM and colab notebook, I'm trying to use opensource large language model for my task, but while processing on google colab, Its getting crashed, may be because of limited RAM.
So I'm trying to access the GPU provided in colab for my task and I used following code to use GPU for processing purpose

```
model_id = "EleutherAI/gpt-neo-2.7B"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id).to(torch.device('cuda'))
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_new_tokens=512, device_map='auto'
)
```

Now I'm getting following error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2211 
   2212 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper_CUDA__index_select)
```

Thanks for help in advance!

I'm trying to use gpu for processing large language model on googal colab. but colab provides only 12GB of CPU and It provides 16GB of GPU so GPU works well.